# The function $f:X\rightarrow X$ is defined in such a way: $f(x)=x-\frac1x, f^{(1)}(x)=f(x), f^{(n)}(x)=f\left(f^{(n-1)}(x)\right)$

Tags: functions

> Let the set $X=\mathbb Q / \{-1;0;1\}$. The function $f:X\rightarrow X$ is defined in such a way:
> $$f(x)=x-\frac1x, f^{(1)}(x)=f(x), f^{(n)}(x)=f\left(f^{(n-1)}(x)\right), n\in \mathbb N.$$
> Is there an $x \in X$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists $y \in X$ such that $f^{(n)}(y)=x$?

#### My work so far:

Let $\frac mn \in X$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then $$f(\frac mn )=\frac mn - \frac nm =\frac {m^2-n^2}{mn}.$$
$\gcd(m^2-n^2,mn)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k \geq 1$ let $$X_k = \left\{\frac{n}{m} \in X \:|\: \text{gcd}(n,m) = 1, m = a_1 \cdots a_k \text{ for some } a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{1,0,-1\}\right\}.$$
Note that $X = X_1 \supset X_2 \supset \dots $ with $\bigcap_{i} X_i = \emptyset$. In fact, if $\frac{n}{m} \in X$ with $\gcd(n,m) = 1$, then we can consider the prime factorization of $m$, that is, $m = p_1 \cdots p_{k'}$ and then we have $\frac{n}{m} \in X_{k'}$ but $\frac{n}{m} \notin X_{k' + 1}$.

Note that your own computation shows that $f(X_k) \subseteq f(X_{k + 1})$ and so we have $f^{(i)}(X) \subseteq X_i$ for all $i \geq 1$ (by induction, if you like).

It follows that we have 
 $$\bigcap_{i} f^{(i)}(X) \subseteq \bigcap_i X_i = \emptyset$$
which shows that the answer to you question is No.